# using a struct member as array size in the same struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm new in structured c coding.I don't know if I can define a structure as follows:

```
typedef struct command_struct {
    uint8_t com_byte_num;
    uint8_t command_bytes[com_byte_num];
    } command;
```

and use it in another struct:

```
typedef struct commands_struct {
    command poll_dig;
    command poll_joy;
    command poll_all;
    command enter_config;
    command exit_config;
    command conf_set_analog;
    command conf_set_digital;
    command conf_vib_off;
    command conf_joy_only;
    command conf_joy_press;
} commands;
```

the `uint8_t    command_bytes[com_byte_num];` part is what I'm not sure about.

Comment: I don't know if I can use a struct member as array size in the same struct

Comment: I didn't see you used the same name. No you cannot. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: He's trying to use a VLA in a struct, similar to how they are passed to functions. But it is not allowed.

Comment: You can't. Your compiler will tell you so, btw. A top-level flexible array member would work for a single command, but that idea goes south as soon as you start stacking them up like you are.

Comment: command_bytes[] size should be flexible.

Comment: thank you for your help. So I would use another method.

Comment: It's my first question on stackoverflow. you guys are awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do the `uint8_t command_bytes[com_byte_num];` in standard C — the array size must either be fixed (constant) or you need the notation `uint8_t command_bytes[];`, which is called a 'flexible array member'.

*(However, see another answer about VLAIS — variable-length arrays in a structure.  Note, however, that such arrays can only be compiled by GCC, and they can only be defined inside a function, which vastly complicates the process of passing pointers to such structures to other functions.)*

If you use a flexible array member, you then cannot create the second structure.  You could do it if it contains pointers to the `command` elements, but not if it contains the actual `struct command` elements.  One of two things will happen:

1. The compiler complains you can't do it.
2. The compiler lets you do it, but all the `command` elements have a zero-size `command_bytes` member.

Neither is helpful to you.  Given the code:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct command_struct
{
    uint8_t com_byte_num;
    uint8_t command_bytes[];
} command;

typedef struct commands_struct
{
    command poll_dig;
    command poll_joy;
    command poll_all;
    command enter_config;
    command exit_config;
    command conf_set_analog;
    command conf_set_digital;
    command conf_vib_off;
    command conf_joy_only;
    command conf_joy_press;
} commands;
```

the command:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c fla.c
```

compiles the file OK (with GCC 4.8.2 on Mac OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks).  If you add `-pedantic`, then you get a screed of errors such as:

```
fla.c:11:13: error: invalid use of structure with flexible array member [-Werror=pedantic]
     command poll_dig;
```

If you change the code as shown below, even the pedantic compilation is happy:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct command_struct
{
    uint8_t com_byte_num;
    uint8_t command_bytes[];
} command;

typedef struct commands_struct
{
    command *poll_dig;
    command *poll_joy;
    command *poll_all;
    command *enter_config;
    command *exit_config;
    command *conf_set_analog;
    command *conf_set_digital;
    command *conf_vib_off;
    command *conf_joy_only;
    command *conf_joy_press;
} commands;
```

Answer (score 0):

VLAIS (variable-length arrays in structs) is permissible in gcc (and the newest C-standards, I think), but the variable array must always be the last member of the struct (so the compiler knows where all members are...). In partiular this means: 
 1. There can be only one! (variable-lenght array, that is...) 
 2. If the struct is a member of another struct, it again has to be the last member of that struct.

Comment: Are you thinking of flexible array members?

Comment: No. VLAIS is a thing in gcc. It's one reason you need gcc to build the Linux kernel, because other compilers don't support it (yet).

Comment: OK; then you would seriously improve your answer by providing links to the material about VLAIS.  I found, rather easily, [Variable Length Arrays in Structs (VLAIS)](http://www.linuxplumbersconf.org/2013/ocw/proposals/1221), which is not a ringing endorsement of the feature — it is a request for the Linux kernel developers to remove the feature from the kernel source code.

Comment: Well, I don't see anything wrong with correct use of VLAIS. From what I remember, VLAIS was a candidate for inclusion into the next C-standard (which was to be C-14, but well...I'm not holding my breath). You're right though, it wouldn't be a good fit for the original question.

Comment: I see nothing at the [ISO/IEC JT1/SC22/W14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/) web site — the C standard committee's web site — to indicate that VLAIS is under discussion.  Can you point to documentation on it?